# Magento: Filtering a getCollection is not working

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework, magento

My getCollection code is providing the wrong query string (i think).

I have a table called banner which I can load all records from easy enough. When I try to filter it I'm getting errors.

Here is the code:

```
$banner = Mage::getModel('banner/banner')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('group', array('eq'=>'search_group'));
```

The page crashes and I get this error:

```
1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group = 'search_group')' at line 1";i:1;s
```

As you can see it seems like the code is messing up the quotes after group.

```
'group = 'search_group')'
```

Can anyone advice on how to fix this?

Thanks,

Billy

Comment: note i've also tried 'like' instead of 'eq'..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`group` is an SQL keyword. If `group` is also an attribute name you'll need to escape it somehow. Try using backticks (the typically unused key below <kbd>Esc</kbd>).

```
$banner = Mage::getModel('banner/banner')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('`group`', 'search_group');
```

Answer (score 3):

You're misinterpreting the error text.

```
 to use near 'group = 'search_group')'
```

The outer quotes are the error messages way of blocking something off as code.  This probably would have been clearer

```
 to use near [group = 'search_group')]
```

It's always best to look at the select your collection is using (assuming a a non-eav collection here, given your Module Creator style class alias) and try running in directly in your MySQL client (PHPMyAdmin, Command Line app, Query analyzer, Sequel Pro, etc.)

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
echo (string) $widget->getSelect();
echo "\n";
var_dump ( (string) $widget->getSelect());
Mage::Log((string) $widget->getSelect());
exit;
```

Seeing the entire query in context usually makes spotting an error easier.

Answer (score 2):

One way will be:-

Write the following function in your collection class:-

```
public function setGroupBy($group)
{
    $this->getSelect()->group($group);
    return $this;
}
```

Then you can use it like:-

```
$banner = Mage::getModel('banner/banner')->getCollection()->setGroupBy('search_group');
```

Hope this helps.